# Append class based on originating class name

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there anyway with JavaScript to add an additional class to every element that has a certain class on the page.

So for example:

```
<div class="but-class">Button</div>
```

but I want to manipulate this so it adds a class (with a counter to the end)

```
<div class="but-class custom-class1"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
(function() {
    var elements;
    //store the collection of matching elements
    elements = document.querySelectorAll(".but-class");
    // loop through the collection appending your new class
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) { 
       elements[i].classList.add('custom-class'+i); // append the value of 'i' to your class name
    }
}());
```

```css
.custom-class0 {
    color: green;
}
.custom-class1 {
    color: red;
}
.custom-class2 {
    color: blue;
}
.custom-class3 {
    color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div class="but-class">Button</div>
<div class="but-class">Button</div>
<div class="but-class">Button</div>
<div class="but-class">Button</div>
```

EDIT

I've wrapped the code in a self invoking anonymous function to prevent `var elements` existing globally.

Comment: To make that work, you'll need to alter:
elements[i].classList.add('custom-class1');
to:
elements[i].classList.add('custom-class'+i);

Comment: Also, `.classList` [doesn't enjoy complete cross-browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist), notably in IE8 and 9. Might want to fall back to: `elements[i].className = elements[i].className + " custom-class" + i;`

Comment: I missed the part about the counter

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn: (upsidedown dropping my display)the counter part was introduced after the edit, I was wondering where it came from too. +1 Michael for pointing that out anyway :)